# Low impact migration path to the latest version of AutoMapper from 4.2.X

Tags: c#, automapper

I am going to attempt to migrate to the latest stable version of auto mapper. The current version used is 4.2.1.0.

There are more than 500 occurrences using 70+ entity maps in the form of:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Data.Entities.Entity, Domain.Models.Entity>();
...
Mapper.Map<Data.Entities.Entity, Domain.Models.Entity>(x)).ToList();
```

I am looking for migration suggestions from people who may have successfully migrated from 4.2.x. Hopefully I can find a migration path with minimal refactoring.

Comment: http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/5.0-Upgrade-Guide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move all of those to a single `Mapper.Initialize` call, though typically we have each of those organized inside a `Profile`. If you're comfortable with regular expressions, you should be able to use it to output all of those occurrences into a single file. Something like `/Mapper\.CreateMap.*;/` (you might have to tweak to get statements that span lines).

Once you have all the `CreateMap` calls gathered, you just need to wrap that in:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap(...);
});
```

You're replacing `Mapper.CreateMap` with `cfg.CreateMap`, so that's a straightforward text replacement.

Then you can use regular expressions again to not just match those original occurrences of `Mapper.CreateMap` and remove them.

This is also the technique I use when I've migrated ORMs, regular expressions to get me 90-100% of the way there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you partition app code based on profiles? Suppose there are like 10-20 entities that are seldom used and another group of entities that are used all the time. Is there a way to configure seldom used groups only when hit the first time? Or is it no big worry/penalty to configure all upfront and at once?

Comment: No real big worry, but for very large applications you can turn the up-front compilation off (see the docs). I don't really partition profiles for performance, just for organization/sanity